# Smarty Dropdown list change image on select

Tags: image, select, drop-down-menu, smarty

i can't get this to work in smarty template (.tpl), although it works fine when using plain html. When user selects from dropdown, the image gets replaced. What is happening in template is the replaced image shows blank, which suggests it can't find the src.

```
{literal}
<script>
function displayResult(selTag)
{
var x=selTag.options[selTag.selectedIndex].text;
alert("You selected: " + x);
document.getElementById('temp_image').src='images/'+ x +'.jpg';
}
</script>
{/literal}

<div class="configoptions">
{foreach from=$configurableoptions item=configoption}
{if $configoption.optiontype eq 1}
<select name="configoption[{$configoption.id}]" id="configoption[{$configoption.id}]"     onchange="displayResult(this); recalctotals();">
{foreach key=num2 item=options from=$configoption.options}
<option value="{$options.id}"{if $configoption.selectedvalue eq $options.id}   selected="selected"{/if}>{$options.name}</option>
{/foreach}
</select>
<br />

<img id="temp_image" src="images/templates/{$options.name}.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

you've defined {$options} inside a foreach loop containing the elements from {$configoption.options} which itself contains items from {$configurableoptions}. Unfortunately this definition is out of scope since its outside the foreach-loop:

```
<img id="temp_image" src="images/templates/{$options.name}.jpg">
```

To (by default) display the first element of {$options} you could try something like this:

```
<img id="temp_image" src="images/templates/{$configurableoptions[0].options[0].name}.jpg">
```